# Implementing in-app purchase refunding in Android

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, android-library

I'm currently using [this](https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3) library to implement in-app billing in my application. I choose to use this library because of the simplicity.

This is how I implemented it:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button buyButton;
BillingProcessor bp;
TextView freeorfull;

String LICENSE_KEY = "MyKey";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    freeorfull = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.freeorfull);

    buyButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buyButton);

    buyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (!BillingProcessor.isIabServiceAvailable(getApplicationContext())) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please upgrade Android Market/Play store to version >= 3.9.16",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {

                bp.purchase(MainActivity.this, "myProductKey");

            }

        }
    });

    buyit();

    if (bp.isPurchased("mybuyfullversion")) {

        freeorfull.setText("FULL oncreate");

    }


}

public void buyit() {
    bp = new BillingProcessor(this, LICENSE_KEY, new BillingProcessor.IBillingHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onProductPurchased(@NonNull String productId, @Nullable TransactionDetails details) {
            freeorfull.setText("FULL in buyit");

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onProductPurchased",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onBillingError(int errorCode, @Nullable Throwable error) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onBillingError",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            if (bp.isPurchased("mybuyfullversion")) {

                freeorfull.setText("FULL oncreate");

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onBillingInitialized() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onBillingInitialized",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }

        @Override
        public void onPurchaseHistoryRestored() {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onPurchaseHistoryRestored",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });

}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (!bp.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if (bp != null) {
        bp.release();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}

}
```

I tried testing refunding users from the Google Play Console, after some time the purchase is refunded and the user(me) receives the money back, but the application still display that the item was purchased.

I'm looking for a way to check if the user was refunded, then change the UI/TextView back to "Free Version".

I have seen that the following can be used:

```
Purchase removeAdsPurchase = inventory.getPurchase(SKU_REMOVE_ADS);
if(removeAdsPurchase != null) {
   int purchaseStateForRemoveAds = removeAdsPurchase.getPurchaseState();
if(purchaseStateForRemoveAds == 1) {
   //Do cancelled purchase stuff here
}
else if(purchaseStateForRemoveAds == 2) {
   //Do refunded purchase stuff here
}
}
```

But this library doesn't have a `Purchase` [class](https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3/tree/master/library/src/main/java/com/anjlab/android/iab/v3) and I don't understand what the inventory refers to.

It is my understanding that I should get the PurchaseState to check if the purchase was refunded. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after a lot of struggling and misleading information, like the answer on this question I finally know why this is happening.

After a user buys a product, the SKU remains valid, no matter what. YES, even if you refund a product.

I spoke to Google Play support and they said the only way to check whether a product was cancelled or refunded is to use the Voided Purchase API. So using Oauth2 you will be able to use the products token and Voided Purchase API to check if the product is valid or not:

[image: screenshot]

It is ok to use bp.isPurchased("yourSKU") to check if your product was purchased successfully.

The only feasible way (in my opinion, and Google's opinion) to check the status of you SKU/Token is to make use of the Voided Purchase API.

Answer (score 1):

This was how I resolved a similar problem using the same billing library. In order to reset the app after refund, you must call the **bp.loadOwnedPurchasesFromGoogle()** method either the BuyActivity or anywhere you can check for purchase status. **Please note that the method**

```
   bp.loadOwnedPurchasesFromGoogle()
```

will **take sometime to update purchase update from Google server so don't wait for it.**

So to check if the item is purchased or not(which includes refunding), try this:

```
 if(bp.isPurchased(PRODUCT_ID)){
      // item is purchased  
 }
 else{ 
        //item not purchased any longer so it is up for buy
 }
```